# How to change font color on hover in Next.js and Tailwind.css

Tags: typescript, next.js, tailwind-css

I made a Navbar component that have users see a purple link when they navigate to Home, Projects, etc. I can see the purple on hover when the background is dark but when its light, its green. How would I go about if I were to want the text hover to purple when my background is light.

Navbar.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Navbar() {
  const hoverStyle = { color: '#7E0ACB' };

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 left-0 w-full flex justify-between p-12 bg-transparent z-10 text-`your text`white mix-blend-difference">
      <div className='text-3xl'>Long Tang</div>
      <ul className="flex text-xl">
        <li className="mx-4 hover:text-purple-600">
          <Link href="/" passHref>
            Home
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-4  hover:text-purple-600">
          <Link href="/about" passHref>
            About
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-4  hover:text-purple-600">
          <Link href="/projects" passHref>
            Projects
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-4  hover:text-purple-600">
          <Link href="/research" passHref>
            Research
          </Link>
        </li>
        <li className="mx-4  hover:text-purple-600">
          <Link href="/contact" passHref>
            Contact
          </Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

globals.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

:root {
  --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0; /* black */
  --background-rgb: 255, 255, 255; /* white */
  --hover-color-rgb: 126, 10, 203; /* purple */
}

body {
  color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
  background: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
}

.hover-text-purple-600:hover {
  color: var(--hover-color);
}
```

I went to the tailwind configuration file and modify the colors and still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you need to update the "--hover-color-rgb" variable in your global.css file to reflect the purple color when the background is light. Here's how you can do it:

```
    global.css
    @tailwind base;
    @tailwind components;
    @tailwind utilities;
    
    :root {
      --foreground-rgb: 0, 0, 0; /* black */
      --background-rgb: 255, 255, 255; /* white */
      --hover-color-rgb: 126, 10, 203; /* purple */
      --hover-color-light-bg-rgb: 126, 10, 203; /* purple */
    }
    
    body {
      color: rgb(var(--foreground-rgb));
      background: rgb(var(--background-rgb));
    }
    
    .hover-text-purple-600:hover {
      color: var(--hover-color);
    }
    
    .hover:text-purple-600:hover {
      color: rgb(var(--hover-color-light-bg-rgb));
    }
```

In the updated code, I added a new variable called "--hover-color-light-bg-rgb" and set it to the same purple color as "--hover-color-rgb". Then, I applied the new color to the "hover:text-purple-600" class, which is used for hover effect in your Navbar component.
By making these changes, the text will appear purple when hovering over the link, regardless of the background color being light or dark.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement dark/light mode using react context or state or any other solutions then you can use [this link](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode) from tailwind to implement proper class names for each mode.

```
<h3 class="text-slate-900 dark:text-white">Sample Text</h3>
```